# Pandas Series, need to save it as CSV properly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have this:

```
df = df['CarModel'].groupby(df['Annum']).value_counts()
df = df.groupby(level=0).nlargest(10).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

which works perfectly fine on cmd and shows exactly what I want.

when I save this to .csv :

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=True)
```

the csv file columns are like this:

```
Annum,CarModel,CarModel
```

i want it to be

```
Annum,CarModel,Count
```

also is it possible to just make this into a dataframe so that i can use pivot tables etc?

Comment: What do you mean "make this into a dataframe"? It is a dataframe in python when you export it to csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using `groupby()` the aggregated column gets renamed to the function passed. Therefore, before saving it you should rename it (you can do it in a separate line too):

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).nlargest(10).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).rename(columns={'count':'CarModel'})
```

Given the error you share, you might be working with a series, therefore please try:

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).nlargest(10).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).to_frame().rename(columns={'count':'CarModel'})
```

Comment: TypeError: rename() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'